# Gitlab predefined variables not populating

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a runner with a tag set up, and a working `.gitlab-ci.yml` file;
the pipeline via the `yml` runs a script to do lint checks on all changed files and returns the results fine. The second job in the `yml` is supposed to be triggered upon solely merge requests to check for conflicts, but isn't being triggered or run.

Either way, I can't get most predefined vars to populate even for the first job/stage. I can get $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME and commit messages and commit ref sha etc; but I need things like:

```
$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME and 
$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
```

which are both returning blank...

any help is appreciated!